# How to add a fieldset in EXTJS on button click

Tags: javascript, extjs, clone

My problem is when I click Add button it needs to add a `fieldset` ("rulepanel") after the previous `fieldset`, but in my code if I execute it the new `fieldset` is added on top of the previous (I can be able to notice it as the letters are getting bold when click on Add button).

**This is my code:**

```
var rulepanel = {
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    border: false,
    itemId: 'rule',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'value',
            name: 'value',
            allowBlank: false,
            placeholder: 'value'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            id: 'add',
            text: 'Add',
            handler: function (button, event) {
                me.insert(rulepanel);
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            id: 'branch',
            text: 'Branch'
        }]
    }]
};

Ext.apply(me, {
    items: [rulepanel]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like below:-

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Add',
    handler: function (button, event) {
        button.up('fieldset').insert(rulepanel);
    }
}
```

You can find running example [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gn4).

Hope this will help you.